# How can I apply bounding box for a discontiguous region in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am trying to apply a bounding box for the discontiguous region in the sample below. I found something in Matlab help docs on `regionprops` but it did not explain anything about how to do it. I need the smallest Box that can contain all the blobs in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, when introduced with a `logical` type input mask, [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) automatically apply [`bwlabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) to the mask and computes properties for each connected component of the input mask.
In your case, this is not a desirable behavior, since you want all the white pixels to be treated as part of the same component. To overcome this default behavior you simply need to cast the input mask from `logical` to other data type.

```
st = regionprops( uint8( BW ), 'BoundingBox' ); %// cast to uint8
rect = st.BoundingBox; %// the bounding box of all white pixels

%// display the results
figure;
imshow( BW, 'border', 'tight' ); 
hold on;
rectangle('Position', rect, 'EdgeColor', 'r', 'LineWidth', 1.5 );
```

Resulting with
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the respond but Your code still Box only a segment of the region.

Comment: @ASpac please see my edit - result on your input image. Please also note that in the image you provided the first column and last row are NOT black, I removed them as outliers.

Comment: I did the following:
`>> I5(:,1)=0;
>> I5(256,:)=0;
>> st = regionprops( uint8( I5 ), 'BoundingBox' ); %// cast to uint8
rect = st.BoundingBox; %// the bounding box of all white pixels

%// display the results
figure;
imshow( I5, 'border', 'tight' ); 
hold on;
rectangle('Position', rect, 'EdgeColor', 'r', 'LineWidth', 1.5 );`

and I got this error:
Error using rectangle
Width and height must be > 0

Comment: It worked!, it was the problem with uint8, i used im2uint8 and it worked. Thank you

Comment: Why on earth why `regionprops` have this behavior... This saved me some time.